# Как найти неактивный элемент в unity программно

Tags: c#, unity3d

В сцене есть неактивный элемент. Как его найти программно ? Я пробовал искать по тегу просто искать возвращает null как будто его и нету.

```
GameObject go1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tag");  // null
GameObject go2 = GameObject.Find("P_Complete");             // null
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[GameObject.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)**

> Finds a GameObject by name and returns it.
>
> This function only returns **active** GameObjects. If no GameObject with
>   name can be found, null is returned. If name contains a '/' character,
>   it traverses the hierarchy like a path name.

---

```
public static class GameObjectExtension {
    public static Object Find(string name, System.Type type) {
        Object[] objects = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(type);
        foreach(var obj in objects) {
            if(obj.name == name) {
                return obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static GameObject Find(string name) {
        return Find(name, typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
void TestMethod() {
    GameObject obj = GameObjectExtension.Find("GameObject");
    if (obj) {
        obj.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

Данный подход очень, очень и еще раз очень медленный. Использовать его нужно только в самых крайних случаях. Сама проблема поиска неактивных объектов зачастую возникает из-за неправильной архитектуры, такие проблемы обычно решаются через ручную установку референсов.

Comment: Спасибо вроде все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Эта функция возвращает любой объект Юнити, который загружен включая префабы, текстуры итд, в том числе и отключенные геймобджекты

```
Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<T>()
```